# DataGridView Cell Value Increment

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to increase the value of the cell in the row by 1, how can i do this? Have tried the following:

```
dataGridViewX1.Rows[dataGridViewX1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value =+ 1;
```

Comment: you will have get the value parse it and then increase it by 1, `Value` will return you object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add as `Value` for `datagridview` is of type object. so you will have to parse the value using `int.TryParse` (so in case if the cell contains an invalid value like text the parse would fail and you can change the behavior depending on your requirement) and then add 1 to it and assign it back to the cell.

Also you can also use `dataGridViewX1.CurrentRow.Cells[2]`

Answer (score 1):

`(int)(dataGridViewX1[row_index][column_index].Value) += 1`

Comment: I doubt if this is going to compile

Answer (score 1):

.Value is of type object, so ++ or += won't work.

Try:

```
int value = (int)dataGridViewX1.Rows[dataGridViewX1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value;
dataGridViewX1.Rows[dataGridViewX1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value = value + 1;
```